# Globalization of controller names and actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to create "aliases" of my controllers and actions, instead of adding one more item to the URL to indicate the language?

Example:

For English:

```
/controllerNameInEnglish/actionNameInEnglish
```

For Portuguese:

```
/nomeControladorEmPortugues/nomeAcaoEmPortugues
```

The Portuguese version must call the same action as the URL for English.

Comment: You can either answer your own question with your link or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check out a plugin called [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/#localizing-urls) that can help you archieve this. The great thing about it is that it's going to be [included by default](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap) in future versions of ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore this question. I just found the answer on http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx